# Subgroup generated by two subgroups in GAP

Tags: gap

I'm new to GAP and I'm not sure if MSE is the correct place to ask this. 
Let $G$ be a group with subgroups $H$ and $K$. How do I find input a command to find the subgroup generated by them both i.e. $\langle H, K \rangle$?

Comment: Subgroup generated by two subgroups? Did you mean their join?

Comment: @KennyLau, yes, precisely the join of $H$ and $K$

Answer (score 1):

Using `Group(..)` in conjunction with `GeneratorsOfGroup(..)` seems possible, although I'm not sure if this is the best way.  As a toy example:

```
gap> G:=SymmetricGroup(100);
Sym( [ 1 .. 100 ] )
```

Starting with a large group

```
gap> H:=Subgroup(G,[Random(G),Random(G),Random(G),Random(G)]);
<permutation group with 4 generators>
gap> K:=Subgroup(G,[Random(G),Random(G),Random(G),Random(G)]);
<permutation group with 4 generators>
```

and two subgroups.  We compute generators:

```
gap> gH:=GeneratorsOfGroup(H);;
gap> gK:=GeneratorsOfGroup(K);;
```

And take the group generated by the union of their generators:

```
gap> HJoinK:=Group(Union(gH,gK));
<permutation group with 8 generators>
```

Comment: One may need to take care that the resulting group is recognised as a subgroup in appropriate subgroups and their supergroup. Look at closures of subgroups here: https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap39.html#X7B855B0485C3C6C5